# When is it appropriate, if at all, to use the suffix "ish"?

Tags: meaning, suffixes

When is it appropriate, if at all, to use the suffix `ish`?

Consider the following:

> She was a largish woman

According to [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define%3a+largish) the word *largish* is defined as *somewhat large*. However, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/largish) seems to redirect the search phrase to *large* instead.

I have seen people abuse this quite a bit. When does one draw the line when using this suffix? Or does it have no place in formal english?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you could make the argument that the *-ish* suffix should not be used in formal English to create ad-hoc words on the spot, like "largish".  There is nothing grammatically wrong — you will, of course be understood — but it has a definite informal connotation. However, there are a number of established words, e.g. *impish*, *boorish*, *devilish*, *sheepish*, etc., where *-ish* is accepted in all contexts, including formal ones.

Comment: All of your usage examples show it affixed to nouns, not adjectives. For adjectives (and sometimes adverbs), "ish" shows an approximation, but for nouns, marks a quality: "impish" does not mean "approximately an imp" but rather "like an imp". There are two very different uses at work here, and arguably only the adjective suffix is the informal one.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that you can attach *-ish* to any noun (or even most nouns) and have a formally acceptable word.  If I said something is *car-ish* or *table-ish*, it would sound quite informal, though understandable.  I maintain that the distinction is really whether the word is established or created on the fly.  There just happen to be few established *-ish* words whose stem is an adjective (for whatever reason).

Comment: Would you say that the same reasoning applies to the use of -ee to create words such as chattee (passive person in a chat) as opposed to established words such as referee or employee? Is the -ish construction more or less acceptable than the -ee construction?

Answer (score 7):

Adding the "ish" suffix to a word X is a colloquial way to say that something is "somewhat" X, "approximately" X, "rather" X, etc.

1. She was a largish woman. ⇒ She was a rather large woman.
2. She will be here by fiveish. ⇒ She will be here by any time close to five o'clock.
3. The boy is fiveish. ⇒ The boy is five years old or about that age.
4. The interior has niceish plastics covering the dash and the doors ⇒ The interior has rather nice plastics covering the dash and the doors.
5. The exam went well, ish. ⇒ The exam went fairly well.

[See Wictionary page here.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ish)

Comment: To me, examples 1-3 sound pretty standard, while 4 and 5 are very colloquial.  "The exam went well, ish" is definitely a "trendy" speech pattern.

Comment: Or, as Steve from "Blue's Clues" said "I was fame-ish"

Answer (score 3):

As an aside, sometimes (in British conversational English at least), people use 'ish' on it's own:

```
"So, are you happy with your new job?"
"Ish."
```

Comment: Very trendy with the younger set.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard it being used in this context before. But then again, I'm not British.

Comment: What?! The way I speak is "trendy"? I may have to change.

Comment: This usage is often accompanied by holding your hand out flat, palm down and wiggling it to denote doubt.

Answer (score -1):

See [this link](http://books.google.com/books?id=1OVIqCV57pYC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=ish%20suffix%20informal&source=bl&ots=K1nVdH4q5v&sig=vCYgmQy7M0-vhoAhTkqQP0YpkIw&hl=en&ei=Bn1hTcLIHsP88Ab769mjDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a summary here (in case the link ever disappears; this is standard practice at EL&U).