# Are there any rules/patterns for selecting "ish" vs "like" as a suffix?

Tags: suffixes

This question arose on a [comment thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19403/use-of-the-suffix-ish/19420?noredirect=1#comment35954_19420) over on ELL. Are there any rules or patterns for when we should/do select "ish" as a suffix, rather than "like"? Some examples discussed were that *birdlike* comes naturally and is easily understood to mean *like or in a manner such as that of a bird*, but no native speaker would come up with *birdish*. As for the opposite, there are words such as *cliquish*, which *clique-like* would never be substituted for.

Another interesting point that FumbleFingers raised in that discussion is that we have some words which take the suffix *ish* but clearly and recognizably do not mean "x-like", such as "sheepish". (Perhaps the *origin* of sheepish is something along the lines of that sheep (the animal) act sheepish, but when you say "He looked away sheepishly" you don't mean "he looked away in a manner similar to that of a sheep.")

Comment: See also https://glossophilia.org/2014/10/ish-esque-or-y-theyre-a-lot-like-each-other-ish/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terms of etymology, [-ish is a diminutive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18826/how-did-ish-suffix-come-to-denote-the-approximate-meaning-of-the-word-it-is-a?rq=1). It often carries a negative context: childish, churlish, clownish, cliquish, selfish, foolish, boyish, girlish, sheepish.

Compare with: adultish, heroish, geniusish ... these don't work. Adult-like, hero-like, genius-like: these sound more correct.

Compare directly childish and child-like. The former has a negative connotation (acting spoilt). The latter has a more neutral or even positive connotation (physical appearance, innocence, purity).

So though it's not a hard-and-fast rule, -ish, with its roots as a diminutive, is often used as an adjective that expresses negative traits of the noun to which it is appended. On the other hand, -like (and -esque) refer to a more neutral, objective resemblance to the noun.

Another use of -ish would include approximations for colours – such as greenish, bluish, redish – and quantities – such as fortyish, fiftyish.

A related use of -ish is to indicate "almost", particularly when paired with an adjective: cleverish, tallish, smallish, darkish, etc. (This is slightly different from approximation in that fortyish would indicate "around forty, possibly over", whereas tallish would indicate "almost or barely tall".)

All cases relate to -ish being diminutive-ish.

Comment: This is a fascinating thought process! It hadn't occurred to me before, but it makes a lot of sense. Thank you! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [magic of `grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) has produced two files,

- [one file of *-ish* words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/ishwords.txt)
  and
- [one file of *-like* words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/likewords.txt)

Feel free to figure out the rules that they follow.
And to find counterexamples to others' rules.

Comment: The '-like' file seems to have 'et' its word breaks. The '-ish' file is fine.

Comment: @martha When I load the "like" file, Chrome tells me it's in Afrikaans and asks if I want to translate ;). But I think these lists could be really helpful to look at for the purposes of this question!

Comment: Sorry about the file. Some problem with Mac vs DOS vs Unix linebreaks, which can be solved quickly in situ.

Answer (score 1):

Consider: childish vs childlike. Childish gives a passive meaning.
She left him because of his childish behaviour.
But childlike has a different meaning. It is something like /innocent/
She gave a childlike smile.q