# Englishman and British man

Tags: nouns, construction, noun-phrases, demonyms

Why is it Englishman, Frenchman, etc. (one word) but British man (two words)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with etymology and usage.

[Old English](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Englishman&allowed_in_frame=0) made use of compounds:

> Engliscman

The word was in use before, is still today and its spelling has been reformed to Englishman.

There are other words that were in use before and not today:

> Englander

The use of the word *British* may have come into popular use only after, [in the 18th Century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_national_identity), when it became interchangeable with *English*. At the time the English language [did not tend to make use of full word compounds](http://www.jstor.org/pss/486964) that would lead to words like *Britishman*. Moreover, the word *British* means *related to the Britons* (as *yellowish* means *related to yellow*) and it would be used as an adjective to [*British Isles*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=British&allowed_in_frame=0), the people themselves were called *Britons*.

Similar treats are found in French, while no full-word compounds exist today, words like *partout* (*par tout*, lit. "through all", i.e. everywhere), *aujourd'hui* (*au jour d'hui*, lit. "at the day of today", i.e. today) and *beaucoup* (*beau coup*, lit. "a beautiful hit", i.e. a lot) are still in use.

Comment: Nice explanation, but *yellowish* actually means 'somewhat yellow': see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3663/8019

Comment: @TimLymington: *somewhat yellow* and *related to yellow* is barely different on an abstract level, I understand it as a genitive i.e. *belonging to yellow* or *of the yellow class*, you could paraphrase this in many more ways.

Comment: The difference is shown in Jonathan Miller's joke: "I'm not really a Jew. Just Jew-ish, not the whole hog."  If the difference between that and ?'belonging to Jews' isn't important to you, fair enough; but it does exist.

Comment: @TimLymington: I am just pointing out that the -ish is a genitive inflexion, which can be nuanced in its context. I understand the nuance and still you could say the man relates to Jews who is partly Jew, and yellowish relates to yellow. This is defined grammatically as genitive and genitive in and of itself does not tell the degree to which the relation holds. I think the nuance is contextual only.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because Britisher already exists, even as Brit, Briton, even the British.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are a bit wrong, I’m afraid.

The reason is simply because Britain isn’t a country! It’s a sovereign state made up of four countries, England, Wales, Scotland and Northen Ireland. Notice how Englishman, Welshman, Scotsman and Irishman all sound right.

Because Britain is a state, it would be like calling a man from Texas a Texasman, or someone from Alabama an Alabamaman. (Try saying that after a few!)

Comment: I'm glad you edited _all wrong_ to _a bit wrong_. Your point may be valid to some extent but I believe Benjamin's answer, from an etymological point of view, is pretty good.

Comment: I'm glad as well!

Comment: Whereas we do have Americaman, Canadaman and Russiaman?

Comment: Really? From what I've heard, no-one in England or Wales would call an American and Americaman, or any of the others. I have only lived in Wales and England, though.

Comment: But you do get a Yorkshireman.

Comment: Someone from the capital of Bahrain?

Comment: No, my point is that if your reasoning was correct, we would have Americamen, Canadamen, and Russiamen. We don't. Hence the rule you're proposing does not match reality. Hence the rule is incorrect.

Comment: There is also the word Cornishman http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cornishman