# What do you call a Swiss man?

Tags: single-word-requests, demonyms

So we call a French male "Frenchman", an English male "Englishman", and a Dutch male "Dutchman".  what do we call Swiss males?

"Swissman" comes to mind, but it sounds like a cheesy version of Superman, like "Cheddarman" or "Mozzarellaman".

Comment: A Swiss person is called just *the **Swiss***. And that's it. No "**-man**" thing.

Comment: **Swiss** swis/ *noun* 1. a native or inhabitant of Switzerland, or a person of Swiss descent. (https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=define+swiss)

Comment: Remember, "Swissman" **cannot** mean "Swiss male" -- *Man* can and does mean 'person' in such contexts.

Comment: @Kris. So are you saying that my daughter is an 'Englishman'? I'd better wear a suit of armour before I tell her that!

Comment: @WS2 Not necessarily. I am saying that an "Englishman" is not necessarily or always a male. You cannot interpret backwards :)

Comment: @Kris So do you mean she could call herself an 'Englishman' if she wanted to? I think I may need two suits of armour!

Comment: No way. If I say I don't trust an Englishman, I could include someone and his daughter and his aunt in that set. Get the drift?

Comment: @Kris There is something about 'when in a hole, stop.........'

Comment: Related: [Englishman and British man](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54471)

Comment: [Cheesehead](http://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3.1057fmthefan.com/styles/nts_image_cover_tall_775x425/s3/Cheesehead%20Bart775Alt.jpg?itok=XfK3PpeJ&c=97f0233dfaa45b470ffc71304eb6c810), obviously!

Comment: @WS2 suits of armour are not effective protection against the modern Hibernians of either sex.

Comment: This is clearly a thp question [clue: British expression]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are in fact [very few cases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113774/why-do-only-a-few-english-demonyms-indicate-gender) where the customary demonym is *root + -man*— those you have named plus *Irishman*, *Norseman*, *Welshman*, *Scotsman*, and (obsolete, now considered offensive) *Chinaman*, and maybe a few others in Britain like *Yorkshireman* or *Cornishman*.

In the absence of a more established form, the [demonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) is usually the same as the adjectival form. Just as we would speak of an Indonesian, an Omani, or a New Zealander, we would speak of a **Swiss**.

It sounds abrupt, even to this native speaker, not only because it is monosyllabic (e.g. calling someone *a Japanese* also seems off), but because in today's politically correct age, referring to someone solely by their nationality or ethnicity is potentially problematic. It would be preferable to use the demonymic adjective in conjunction with a noun; *Swiss man* would suffice.

Comment: Yorkshire and Cornwall are the only counties of England that allow for this treatment. You cannot, for example say a 'Norfolkman', but you can refer to someone as a Lancastrian, a Devonian, a Cumbrian and a Northumbrian. You can also refer to a Dalesman. But the terms Yorkshireman and Cornishman mean more than simply a resident of those counties. You could, for example, live in New Zealand, and still call yourself a Yorkshireman. These terms connote more than a person's locality, but a certain sense of identity.

Comment: I don't agree that it's automatically "potentially problematic" to refer to someone with a single word referencing their nationality. "An American" is completely fine and I can't imagine it ever being seen as problematic. I think the same goes for any nationality noun ending in "-an". "Swiss" sounding abrupt is a particular feature of that particular word; I don't think it's explainable by reference to the meaning of the word.

Comment: I like "a Swiss." It sounds very nice to me for some reason

Answer (score 5):

A man from Switzerland is called a **Swiss man**.

You can tag the nouns: male; man/men; gentleman; guy/s; woman/women; girl; boy; baby etc.  to any nationality. And rightly so, otherwise phrases like:

> "He married a Swiss"

and

> "The other day while travelling into France by train, we talked to a very friendly Swiss"

are needlessly vague or ambiguous.

Moreover, **Swiss man** should not be spelt as one word. Some other examples are an *Italian man*, a *Brazilian man* a *Chinese man*. I tend to spell **English man** as two words but it can be spelt as one word, likewise **Frenchman** and **Frenchwoman** are commonly used names.

The words Englishman, Englishwoman, Frenchman, Frenchwoman, and Scotsman are [nouns](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/nouns6.php) in their own right.

Even the Swiss news use the term [Swiss man](http://www.thelocal.ch/20130725/prince-georges-website-swiped-by-swiss-man) themselves.

> Prince George's website swiped by Swiss man

Comment: You would really be referring to some 'man' with a qualifier 'Swiss' here -- *Swiss man* is not an expression for a 'male national of Switzerland' as an 'Englishman' or a 'Scotsman'. That way, I could as well refer to 'this Detroit man' and 'that Los Angeles man'. See for example, Gerry Dorrian's answer.

Comment: Likewise with all the other terms: a Chinese person, an Egyptian woman, etc

Comment: @Kris Swiss is the adjective and noun. Swiss man or a Swiss. Swedish man but  a Swede.

Answer (score 4):

I'm Swiss and this has never occurred to me until I read "a Swiss" in an article earlier today. It really does not sound right. If Shakespeare really referred to them as "Switzers", that seems good enough for the rest of us. My suggestion was going to be "an Helvetic" or "an Helvetian", derived from the latin name of the country (Helvetica, which is why the initials of the country are "CH" and why the currency is "CHF"). It may admittedly not be intuitive or obvious to readers, so perhaps this suggestion isn't the way to go.

Comment: Wouldn't you aspirate the _h_? In which case 'An Helvetian' sounds ridiculously stuffy.

Answer (score 2):

Vladimir Nabokov and Shakespeare went with **Switzer**[;](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233792/what-is-it-called-when-something-appears-so-obvious-no-one-expects-it) one need look no further.

> GERTRUDE
>       Alack, what noise is this?
>
> CLAUDIUS Where are my **Switzers**? Let them guard the door.

*Hamlet* 4.5

*(Interestingly, the Russian word for "doorman" is швейцар ["shveĭt͡sar"], perhaps from this usage. But I'm fairly sure "Switzer" indeed means "Swiss guy" in English.)*

> ...with some weird light effects anon, when the torch-bearing **Switzers**
>   are sent to find the body.

*Bend Sinister* 112.

Comment: ...except that few others in the English world use these.

Comment: A Switzer sounds like a drink… perhaps a [Spritzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spritzer) made with Seltzer water.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think you are talking about a [swizzle stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swizzle_stick). P.S.: I like your name.

Comment: OMG, I didn't think I'd live to see Nabakov and the Bard on the same trolley line. Good one, though.

Comment: Shakespeare used  'sneap' for '[a] rebuke' and 'foison' for 'abundance'. He also used 'egregious' in a totally different sense from the default usage of today.

Comment: [This article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4283663) feels the need to gloss "Switzer" as "Swiss", so I'd agree it's not widely known, and perhaps less common than Swiss as a noun.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever the nationality, it is an adjective in a noun phrase, whether you tag on a denominator or gender or other such noun.

So, "I'm a Swiss (man / woman / citizen / denizen / etc.)" is fine. Or then simply say, "I'm Swiss" leaving out the [indefinite] article.

(Please do post a comment if you don't agree with me).

Comment: Please use lower case for adjective and noun phrase. [denominator is for math] :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above; however, another alternative might be "man from Switzerland".