# Alternative for "found something accidentally even when it was lying really close the whole time"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idiom-requests

Let me give you an example of the situation where I would like to use this "word/phrase/idiom/expression". A friend of mine who had a laptop for 3 months now accidentally *discovers* that it is screen-touch enabled when his fingertip brushed against his monitor when he was pointing something to his boss. "Discovered" does seem like a good fit but it sounds pretty dull, at-least in my mind.

I have thought of two phrases: "**right under his nose this whole time**" and "**Eureka Eureka**" when I would like to tell this anecdote to someone but I am not sure if it is appropriate in this instance. Also I need alternatives to carry a humorous tone not bothering about if it is a bit exaggerated form.

Comment: My mother would have said "If it was a snake it woulda bit you", but that's probably a little too dialect for your purposes.

Comment: Actually, it's a case of "**missed** something even when it was lying really close the whole time" rather than one of epiphany -- could be more like  *aha moment* instead.

Comment: Stoney - that's exactly right, and I don't think it's too dialect. Everyone knows that one.

Comment: @JoeBlow Actually although it would be understood in British English, it is not used there. The only other time I have heard this expression is in the film 'Grease'...

Comment: Hi Marv .. hmm, I wonder why our experience is different.  I believe it's pretty common in, for example, Australia.  I may be wrong though.  Good one, thanks.

Comment: @JoeBlow I would guess the reason is that in the UK people do not encounter snakes on a common basis. For example, I am over 50 and I have seen an indigenous snake just once in my life in the wild in the UK :)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there were any!  Didn't St Patrick get rid of them or something??  Good point.

Comment: @JoeBlow No, he was the patron saint of Guiness and the colour Green ;)

Comment: related: [What is it called when something appears so obvious, no one expects it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233792/what-is-it-called-when-something-appears-so-obvious-no-one-expects-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the actual laptop situation you describe, sometimes "realised" (or **"finally realised"**) makes more sense.  You also have **"finally noticed"**.

It's a little clearer than "discovered" which doesn't quite fit. (It's kind of the opposite of a long quest with a discovery at the end ... you know?)

As you already said, "right under his nose this whole time" of course fits perfectly (why are you even asking for another?)  And as Stoney's Mother said "If it was a snake, it woulda bit you." (I also like "If it was a snake, it woulda bit you in the ass.")

Note that often the "correct answer" to SWRs is "there is, simply, NOT exactly an SWR for that" ... and/or ... "well yes you've given the best answer already."

Finally, just a note that

## "facepalm"

is a (funny, I think) recently popular term that is used in situations like this.

[image]

(Interestingly I think you could almost just about start using that as a verb or similar form, for situations such as finding something that was right in front of you ... *"I facepalmed my spectacles this morning - they were on my head the whole time!"*)

Comment: Indeed note my marvellous and charming new question here, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268099/swr-for-just-now-from-my-hand-lost-an-object

Answer (score 6):

The phrase ['hidden in plain sight'](http://www.yourdictionary.com/hidden-in-plain-sight) comes close, in terms of the method of obfuscation, but does not really communicate the accidental location. Still, it may be of some use.

> **hidden-in-plain-sight**
>
> *Adjective* (not comparable)
>
> That [which] seems to be hidden, but actually is not hidden and is easy to be found
>
> *www.yourdictionary.com*

Comment: Just what Marv said.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an *"oldie but goodie"*:

"He touched the screen and, ***lo and behold***, he realized that it was a "touch-screen" computer."

Comment: I wish I had the freedom to accept two answers, so I could have marked yours too.

Answer (score 2):

**Duh**

It has to be pronounced with a certain intonation (high to low and then a bit up again) and a certain facial expression.

Example: Today I figured out my laptop has a touch screen.  Duh!  I've only had it for three months!

(The last part is pronounced with sarcasm.)

This would be a way of poking fun at yourself.  *Duh* means *it should have been obvious*.

Comment: I just thought of another idea, something having to do with "it was staring me in the face."

Answer (score 0):

That would be a ***[serendipitous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/serendipitous)*** discovery.

> Definition of serendipitous in English:
>   adjective
>   Occurring or discovered by chance in a happy or beneficial way:
>   *'a serendipitous encounter'*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/serendipitous

Comment: that is a good suggestion but it doesn't capture the proximity